# C#: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to path is denied When File.Move or File.Delete

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I need to create small console application to move files into separate folders. Everything works fine, I can copy file, until I try to File.Move or File.Delete file, I catch System.UnauthorizedAccessException. What I've tried

1. changing folder permission from code
2. switching from .Net Core to .Net Framework
3. Manually adding permission to folder by rightclicking->Security->Advance
4. tried to change Folder's  Read-only attribute (it always reverts back to readonly, I can't solve this)

I don't know what else I can try and how to solve this problem. The code I wrote is below

```
var pngFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\MSI_PC\Desktop\Test", "*.png",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var pngFile in pngFiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pngFile);

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(pngFile);
            var newFolder = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\MSI_PC\Desktop\Test",
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder);
            var newFileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\MSI_PC\Desktop\Test",
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), fileName);
            File.Copy(pngFile, newFileName, true); //yes, I can use move and have 1 line of code instead of 2. But I need file to be copied, and this line of code works fine
            File.Delete(pngFile); // System.UnauthorizedAccessException. File.Move throws the same exception
        }
```

Comment: you are changing folder permissions, but I guess your issue is with file permissions

Comment: It may be that antivirus still have the file open to analyze it, since you just read from it. You say you can use File.Move, does that work?

Comment: What is the _exact_ value of `pngFile`?

Comment: @vasily.sib i tried  FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pngFile);
                fileInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
It did not help. Files are not readonly

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen File.Move throws exception too. What do you mean "antivirus still have the file open to analyze it"?

Comment: @mjwills Full file path, like this C:/Users/User/Test/image.png

Comment: I doubt it is that - the slash is the one way around.

Comment: @TimurAhmetov just try to do it by yourself. Open this folder in explorer, create subfolder, copy file, delete file. Do you have any issue?

Comment: @mjwills well, this is the exact value "C:\\Users\\MSI_PC\\Desktop\\Test\\2019-12-26_18-25-11.png"

Comment: @vasily.sib I can do this, Ctr-x Ctrl-v works fine

Comment: What is the _exact_ value of `newFileName`?

Comment: Does it work if you disable antivirus? Or sleep for 20 seconds before deleting the file?

Comment: @mjwills newFileName value is "C:\\Users\\MSI_PC\\Desktop\\Test\\2019-12-26_18-25-11\\2019-12-26_18-25-11.png" - a new folder inside folder + filename. Well, File.Copy works . Disabling antivirus or adding Thread.Sleep does not work

Comment: oh, I use Norton Antivirus and it has additional options for file protection. Disabled it and everything worked @mjwills thanks for the advice

Comment: Well, @LasseV.Karlsen mentioned it first. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
private void Copy()
{
    var pngFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop", "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var pngFile in pngFiles)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(pngFile);

       var fileName = Path.GetFileName(pngFile);
       var newFolder = Path.Combine(@"D:\NewPic\");
       Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder);
       string DestPath = newFolder + "\\" + fileName;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[2014 * 1024];
       using (FileStream source = new FileStream(pngFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete))
       {
           using (FileStream dest = new FileStream(DestPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Delete))
           {
              int currentBlockSize = 0;
              while ((currentBlockSize = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
              {
                  dest.Write(buffer, 0, currentBlockSize);
              }
              dest.Close();
           }
           source.Close();
       }
       File.Delete(pngFile); // System.UnauthorizedAccessException. File.Move throws the same exception
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it does not work. Throws exception on File.Delete

Comment: I sent another method for your question. But a friend said you also do not want anything. You can copy and delete data with the stream file. I will send it to you if you wish.

Comment: How do I delete file using filestream?

Comment: The file is copied by streaming, but the same method is used to delete it